# Can't type more than one digit at a time

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a template for a page but I have a problem with the code. When I try to enter more than one digit in the calculator, I have to click on it every time. You can check out the page: https://www.gesher-jds.org/giving-tuesday/

When I try to put more than one number there, I have to click on it. I have no idea what the problem is.

I found out that when I delete the second paragraph of the code ("if..blur');") I can solve it, but then the payment process doesn't work.

```
<<script>   jQuery("#sample-donation2").keyup(function(){
        var keyValue = jQuery(this).val()*2;
        var keyValueOriginal = jQuery(this).val();
        console.log(keyValue);
        jQuery(".multiplyresult2").html("$"+keyValue + ".00");
        jQuery("#give-amount").attr("value" , keyValueOriginal + ".00");
        jQuery("#give-amount").attr("data-amount" , keyValueOriginal);
        jQuery(".give-final-total-amount").html(keyValueOriginal + ".00");
        jQuery(".give-final-total-amount").attr("data-total" , keyValueOriginal);

                if ( jQuery('#give-amount').length > 0 ) {
                jQuery('#give-amount')
                    .val(keyValueOriginal)
                    .focus()
                    .trigger('blur');
        }

        /*jQuery("#give-amount").attr("value" , keyValueOriginal + ".00");
        jQuery("#give-amount").attr("data-amount" , keyValueOriginal);
        jQuery(".give-final-total-amount").html(keyValueOriginal + ".00");
        jQuery(".give-final-total-amount").attr("data-total" , keyValueOriginal);
        jQuery("input[name=give-price-id]").val(0);*/

    });
</script>
<style>


ul#give-donation-level-button-wrap li:last-child {
    display: none;
}
</style>

<?php get_footer();?>
```

Comment: Please share more code.

Comment: Adding more code now. The code below is before the if paragraph.

Comment: <<script> jQuery("#sample-donation2").keyup(function(){
  var keyValue = jQuery(this).val()*2;
  var keyValueOriginal = jQuery(this).val();
  console.log(keyValue);
  jQuery(".multiplyresult2").html("$"+keyValue + ".00");
  jQuery("#give-amount").attr("value" , keyValueOriginal + ".00");
  jQuery("#give-amount").attr("data-amount" , keyValueOriginal);
  jQuery(".give-final-total-amount").html(keyValueOriginal + ".00");
  jQuery(".give-final-total-amount").attr("data-total" , keyValueOriginal);

Comment: @starwars400 There should be a button to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58653032/edit) your question right below the [php] and [wordpress] tags. Use that to add your code to your question with proper formatting.

Comment: Thanks. Just did it.

Comment: Don't focus your other input. That's why you can't type more than 1 number at a time

Comment: So what should I delete?

Comment: Any ideas? How do I solve it?

Comment: Removed the focus and it works! Thanks!